# How do I explicitly set a direct runner with other command line arguments?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I wrote this pipeline but when I run it as a jar it can not find the direct runner when I have it specified in my build.gradle, and when I try to pass the parameter --runner=direct or 
--runner=Directrunner. Below is my code and my build.gradle file. I am running the gradle task fatJar to create the jar navigating to my build/libs folder to run the jar and seeing this error. this is my command I am using `java -jar filepipeline-all-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --input="../testdata" --output="./manifest.json" --runner=DirectRunner`
Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

My  folder structure looks like this:
--src
 --main
  --java
   --com.pipeline
    --BeamPipeline.java

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'

}

group 'com.dustin'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'com.pipeline.BeamPipeline'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}


apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'src.main.java.com.pipeline.BeamPipeline'

dependencies {
    runtime group: 'org.apache.beam', name: 'beam-runners-direct-java', version:'2.8.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.beam', name: 'beam-sdks-java-core', version:'2.8.0'
    runtime group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-jdk14', version:'1.7.25'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'commons-codec', name:'commons-codec', version:'1.12'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180813'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
}
```

Pipeline:

```
package com.pipeline;

import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.*;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.*;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;



public class BeamPipeline {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BeamPipeline.class);
    public static interface MyOptions extends PipelineOptions {

        @Validation.Required
        @Description("Input Path(with gs:// prefix)")
        String getInput();
        void setInput(String value);

        @Validation.Required
        @Description("Output Path (with gs:// prefix)")
        String getOutput();
        void setOutput(String value);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(MyOptions.class);
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

        File dir = new File(options.getInput());
        String output = options.getOutput();

        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
                String inputString = file.toString();
                p
                        .apply("Match Files", FileIO.match().filepattern(inputString))
                        .apply("Read Files", FileIO.readMatches())
                        .apply(MapElements.via(new SimpleFunction<FileIO.ReadableFile, KV<String, String>>() {
                            public KV<String, String> apply(FileIO.ReadableFile file) {
                                String temp = null;

                                try {
                                    temp = file.readFullyAsUTF8String();

                                } catch (IOException e) {

                                }

                                String sha256hex = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex(temp);

                                return KV.of(file.getMetadata().resourceId().toString(), sha256hex);

                            }
                        }))
                        .apply("Print", ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String, String>, Void>() {
                            @ProcessElement
                            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws IOException {

                                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(output,true);
                                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

                                obj.put(c.element().getKey(), c.element().getValue());

                                fileWriter.write(obj.toString());
                                fileWriter.close();

                                log.info(String.format("File: %s, SHA-256 %s", c.element().getKey(), c.element().getValue()));

                            }
                        }));
                }
            p.run().waitUntilFinish();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`beam-runners-direct-java` is added as runtime dependency and hence not added to the fat jar.
You can add `beam-runners-direct-java` as a compile time dependency to use it.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.dustin'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'com.pipeline.BeamPipeline'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}


apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'src.main.java.com.pipeline.BeamPipeline'

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.beam', name: 'beam-runners-direct-java', version:'2.8.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.beam', name: 'beam-sdks-java-core', version:'2.8.0'
    runtime group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-jdk14', version:'1.7.25'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'commons-codec', name:'commons-codec', version:'1.12'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180813'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
}
```

Alternately, if you don not want to package `DirectRunner` with the fatjar and only want to use it for testing, you can create separate `DirectRunner` jar and add it to class part while running the pipeline.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.dustin'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'com.pipeline.BeamPipeline'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}

task directrunnerjar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'com.pipeline.BeamPipeline'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-runtime'
    from { configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}


apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'src.main.java.com.pipeline.BeamPipeline'

dependencies {
    runtime group: 'org.apache.beam', name: 'beam-runners-direct-java', version:'2.8.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.beam', name: 'beam-sdks-java-core', version:'2.8.0'
    runtime group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-jdk14', version:'1.7.25'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'commons-codec', name:'commons-codec', version:'1.12'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180813'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
}
```

`java -cp "libs/myartifact-runtime-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:libs/filepipeline-all-1.0-SNAPSHOT" com.pipeline.BeamPipeline  --input="../testdata" --output="./manifest.json" --runner=DirectRunner`